# converting php variable content to html string

Tags: php, html, parsing, variables

I am parsing data from html using [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

```
$html = file_get_html('www.example.com');
$e= $html->find('div[class=BodyContent]');
```

The variable $e contains html data (divs, imgs, etc).  If I echo it on the screen with a foreach loop, it prints out on the screen perfectly.  How can I convert this $e to a string?  My goal is for it to look like this and use:

```
$x = str_get_html('<div id="BodyContent">Hello</div>
                   <div id="world">World</div>...otherData');
```

How can I do this so $e content displays as regular HTML inside str_get_html?

Update:  The variable $e should contain HTML data after parsing:

```
<div id="BodyContent">
  <div id="somethingelse>
    <p>Some more content</p><a>Some links</a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

The function from SimpleHtmlDom requires parameter 1 to be a string so...I want to convert the variable $e to a string so all these divs and paragraphs can be inserted into the str_get_html('HERE').

Comment: $e is an array of results from the find(). try `echo implode('', $e)` to get a string instead.

Comment: it displayed as formatted text, not as HTML with tags.  I want to be able to put it in str_get_html() as HTML with tags...

Comment: then you need to tell the browser that you're outputting html, e.g. `header('Content-type: text/html')`.

Comment: I don't want to output $e to the browser.  I want to insert it as unformmatted HTML into the str_get_html()...

Comment: then convert to a string and use regular string operations. `"<div>" . implode('', $e) . "</div>"`.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean.  I don't want to make new tags because the variable $e already has content which HAS HTML tags and elements.

Comment: then perhaps you should explaine exactly what bits of `$e` you want to extract, because we're not psychic.

Comment: Please read the original questions where it says the variable $e already has parsed content from a website, so it contains HTML tags and elements.  Which I would like to insert into the str_get_html() so I can modify the content of the original HTML data parsed from a site.

Comment: and that's exactly what we've shown you, and yet you reject it saying that it contains tags. Well, if you don't want the tags, you need to tell us exactly what you DO want to get from that snippet. or maybe it's as simple as `str_get_html(implode('', $e))`. but I'm getting confused, and you seem to be unable to explain this properly.

Comment: I know, I guess I can't get my point across...I updated my questions...maybe that will help?  If I just insert the variable $e into the str_get_html($e), I get Warning:strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array AND Warning:preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in simple_html_dom.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$e` is an array or an object. Casting it to an array will ensure you can implode on it even if its a single object, then implode will call the __toString on all the objects giving you a single html string:

```
$htmlstr = implode("\n", (array) $e);
```

The array casting could be overkill because in order to get just a single object as the return value from `find` you have to call it with a specific index - so presumably you would know whether to cast or not... but if you are juggling `$e` around a bunch it might be easier to just cast it like ive show so it doesnt blow up.

In that case you need to find the Method you want in the API and call it on each element... Id use array_map for this:

```
$htmlstr = implode("\n", array_map(function ($node) { return $node->whatever; }), (array) $e);
```

Comment: using implode it displayed as formatted text.  I want to put HTML with tags inside str_get_html() so I can modify the html with Simple Html Dom parser.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me not understanding all this but it seems like overkill.  The parsed data in the variable $e has an array of HTML tags and elements from the website.  I just want to turn it to a string of tags and elements, not formatted text...I didn't think it would be so difficult...

Comment: Out of curiosity did you dump the string from the `implode` to the browser? If so .. you realize it would be rendered as HTML right? So if you are saying its "formatted" text then i suspect its the html youre looking for since formatted typically means HTML.

Comment: As for what sin the array... they are actually objects, not strings of tags, in order to get the tags you need to get the proper string from them, which has to be accessed via a property or method.

Comment: haha Man, this is getting ridiculous.  Ok, here we go.  The variable $e contains parsed data from a website's body (<div class...><p><otherdivs>...).  When I echo to the browser, it displays the part which I wanted from the website.  I want to modify the parsed data.  With SimpleHTMLDOM parser, str_get_html() requires the parameter to be a string.  So I want to convert that $e variable's contents to a string, as in str_get_html('<div class...><p><otherdivs>...');

Comment: @user2025469: Right, so implode it then load it into `str_get_html` and you should be fine...`str_get_html(implode("\n", (array) $e))`... did you try that? What happened?

Comment: One more thing...why do I at the bottom of the screen get this: "Array132273227UTF-8UTF-8"???  It's not an error or a warning...just that?  It's not in my code or in the code that I parsed anywhere

Comment: Thats a string conversion of an array id assume. Somehow youve gotten another array in there? I dunno post another question with the code that generates it.

Comment: Figured it out...I got rid of a foreach loop and it got rid of that text.  One more quick questions...how can I get rid or hide a "Creating default object from empty value in..."?  The script still displays everything correctly but I get that error sometimes. I understand why it shoes up because on the parsed page sometimes there isn't any data regarding the code being put in and that's ok with me...